# Error SSL CloudFlare install hosting Cpanel "ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH"

Tags: ssl, cpanel, cloudflare

I will share with you a case when installing SSL Free provided by **CloudFlare** and installing
Key + Cert on hosting when accessing with **Chrome** error "**ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH**" try with **Firefox** "**Secure connection failed and firefox did not connect**" I have searched through some informative websites and found out do "**You should turn on 'Always use HTTPS' as well as 'Automatic HTTPS Rewrites' on that SSL/TLS app, this will make sure all resources are loaded over HTTPS including the main page**" and I am using Wordpress source code web, just adding rule in .htaccess force HTTPS solved this error and successfully accessed the website.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Successfully processed

Comment: This error is common if one tries to access a ressource with HTTPS which is not properly enabled for SSL. Might be broken server setup, wrong port in URL, SSL only enabled for IPv4 but not IPv6 etc. Unfortunately not enough details are known (no actual site setup, no URL known you access, ... - i.e. nothing reproducible) to be more specific on what the error is in your case.

Comment: Previously, I used SSL Free of Cpanel, ZeroSSL access was successful, so the error caused by server configuration, port in URL, SSL only enabled for IPv4 but not IPv6 in this case was incorrect, only got an error when adding Cloudflare SSL lead to error and I found the solution as I mentioned and it worked.